# Populates the Necessary Data and skip others

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using `RegexReplace` which populates the necessary data and my formula is working fine but i also want to populate those values which has `(Ordered but Pending)` and the word before it.

My formula populates the value which has `?` sign

There are some words that i want to keep as it is like starting `*** PEELS` and ending like `ZA - Date ***` that ZA and Date can be changed in Data cell.

Your help will be much appreciated.

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(\*{3}.*?)(?:\s*?\.{3}DONE=>.*)?(\*{3})$","$1$2"))
```

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z14J0L8ncK0YOaVSTKoNKwAgeCvibg-B1P3t5PTjFTI/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a pattern to capture until the first occurrence of a date.

Then capture the data like pattern in group 2, as that should be in another place for the final replaced string.

Then match to remove either until repeated parts of (Ordered bu Pending) or match the rest of the line.

At the end capture the asterix pattern.

In the replacement use the 4 groups `$1$3 $2$4`

```php
^(.*?)\s*(-\s*[A-Z]+\s*-\s*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})(?:\s*\.+DONE=>.*?((?:\s*[A-Z]+\s*\(Ordered but Pending\))+)|.*)\s*(\*{3})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lpy4ZH/1)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much can you please look into the last row in the sheet. I have highlighted

Comment: @HSHO Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/cLhGBw/1